# Using participles to short long sentences

Tags: tense, participles

I am confused about using participles to shorten long sentences.

There's a situation where I tried to study but after an hour I found myself getting  nowhere as *I didn't even read a single paragraph*.

I have two questions here—

1. Is the sequence of tense correct? (I mean, is the italicized part  in correct tense or I should have used '**hadn't even read**'?)
2. I want to shorten the italicized part using participles, but doing so I lose the perfect aspect of the action. Can it be done?

Here's what I have come up with –

> I tried to study but after an hour I found myself getting  nowhere as not even reading a single paragraph **by then**.

Comment: It's *entirely* a stylistic choice whether to use Simple Past (with do-support) or Past Perfect in your cited context. But this is irrelevant if you want to "shorten" the text, because ***didn't even read*** and ***hadn't even read*** are exactly the same number of characters. But arguably in ***speech***, the second (Past Perfect) version is very slightly shorter, because it uses past participle ***read*** (pronounced ***red***, which is a "shorter" vowel than the infinitive form pronounced ***reed*** as used in the Simple Past do-support version).

Comment: **There was a situation** - and the word is **paragraph** (you would only use **para** in very informal speech).

Comment: @ Kate Bunting Thankyou for the correction Can I use 'having read'  (I tried to study but after an hour I found myself getting nowhere as not having read a single paragraph by then)

Comment: "didn't even read" sounds like American English and "hadn't even read" sounds like British English. Any AmE speakers care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

The past perfect, "...hadn't even read..." is better because you're referring to the time before the hour was up.

And yes, the sentence can be shortened with "-ing":

> I tried to study, but after an hour I found myself getting nowhere, ***not having read*** even a single paragraph.